# How to get multiple columns in a dataframe from an output into an excel?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am trying to extract the output into an excel file

```
import pandas as pd
file1='excel1.xlsx'
file2='excel2.xlsx'

df1=pd.read_excel(file1)
df2=pd.read_excel(file2)
l=df2['col1'].tolist()

for row in range(len(l)):
    for index,row1 in df1.iterrows():
        l[row].replace(row1['emp'],row1['desc'])
out=[a.replace('','_') for a in l]
length=[len(o) for o in out]

final_df=pd.DataFrame(out,index=df2['col1'],columns=['desc']
final_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

In the above code it giving only out variable result in excel, but I need to get length variable result also in excel.

When I am trying to give length variable in columns, it is giving columns are expected to be 1 but giving 2.

```
 final_df=pd.DataFrame(out,index=df2['col1'],columns=['desc','Length']
 final_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Can anyone please help on how to get both out variable and length variable results in excel?

Answer (score 0):

```
... previous code section

out=[a.replace('','_') for a in l]
length=[len(o) for o in out]

final = {'desc': a, 'Length': length}
final_df=pd.DataFrame(final,
                      index=df2['col1']
final_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```